# Correct Visual Studio Code launch.json to debug WordPress with a Virtual Host on WAMP

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-studio-code, debugging, xdebug

I cannot get Virtual Studio Code PHP debugger to bind and stop at breakpoints when running my localhost WordPress website on a virtual host:

- website URL: `http://mywebsite.local`
- path on disk: `b:/wamp64/www/mywebsite`

I suspect it has something to do with path mappings but have been tearing my hear out for 3 days.

Debugging does work if I run the website directly from localhost, i.e.:

- site URL: `http://localhost/website`
- path on disk: `b:/wamp64/www/mywebsite`

So this confirms Xdebug is working correctly and is configured.  I can also get the virtual host to debug using NetBeans IDE, so the problem appears to be specific to my Virtual Studio Code setup.

I would be grateful for suggestions regarding my `launch.json` file:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
        },
        {
            "name": "Open in Browser",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://mywebsite.local",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "pathMapping": {
                "http://mywebsite.local": "b:\\wamp64\\www\\mywebsite"
            },
        },
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Debug and Open in Browser",
            "configurations": [
                "Listen for Xdebug",
                "Open in Browser"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Make an Xdebug log file (`xdebug.log=c:\tmp\file.txt`, or a better location), with `xdebug.log_level=11` and see what it says about which files breakpoints are set `breakpoint_set` and which files Xdebug sees. The log would be full of them.

Comment: *"`"pathMapping": {"http://mywebsite.local": "b:\\wamp64\\www\\mywebsite"},`"* But path mapping is for *path mappings* (e.g. when your code is executed on a remote system/VM so that the VSCode knowns how to translate remote path to local and other way around) and not URLs... In either case: Xdebug log is the first step to see what is going on here (ideally to get this for both working and not working cases)

Comment: Check the `php.ini` file at the bottom in the XDEBUG config section. Find the `xdebug.mode =` and make sure it has debug in the list  like this `xdebug.mode =develop, debug`

Comment: Make sure you use the wampmanager icon to get to the `php.ini` file `wampmanager->php->php.ini(Apache module)`

Comment: @Derick This was a great tip, thanks.

Comment: @LazyOne - I think complete deleting this might have been the solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the working configuration here for future readers.  Deleting the PathMapping parameter was likely the problem (thanks @LazyOne), but this does not explain the issues I was having prior to adding those lines.  Anyway, compound configuration works to start listening for xdebug and launch chrome to a URL that is based on the current ${workspaceFolderBasename}, i.e. the folder on disk Visual Studio Code currently has open.

Note the userDataDir value forces chrome to re-use the profile associated with your Chrome account that is currently logged in.  I need this because that profile has all the extensions and bookmarks I use to support debugging.  Delete this to have Chrome create a new profile for each session.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://${workspaceFolderBasename}.dyg",
        "userDataDir": "",
    },
],
"compounds": [
    {
        "name": "Debug and Open in Browser",
        "configurations": [
            "Listen for Xdebug",
            "Launch Chrome"
        ]
    }
]
```

}